# Unable to get basic <script> containing onMount and handleClick functions to run clientside in Sapper/Svelte app

Tags: svelte-3, sapper

So I feel like I'm missing something basic, and I hope that I am. I'm building out a simple site in Sapper. I'm using UIKit for styling and some JS (parallax, scrollspy stuff). I'm also just trying write out to the console when a form component is mounted, and write out to the console when I click a button on that form component. Obviously I want more complex functionality, but I wasn't expecting to get hung up on this step.

I'm calling in the UIKit scripts and stylesheets in svelte:head like so:

```
<svelte:head>
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/uikit-3.6.17/css/uikit.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="/uikit-3.6.17/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="/uikit-3.6.17/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</svelte:head>
```

And then I'm trying to console log things in the following script tag:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  export let handleSubmit;
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
      console.log("button clicked");
    };

  onMount(() => {
    console.log("form mounted");
  });
</script>
```

In the browser, "form mounted" is not being logged, and "button clicked" is not being logged on button click. The handleSubmit function is being bound to a pair of buttons, and the form component is being imported into index.svelte. I've seen in the docs that [onMount is not called on a server side component](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount), but I'm fairly certain this component is client side. It could be that I don't understand the distinction.
As far as the handleSubmit function goes, I feel like I have it implemented correctly via the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#on_element_event).

I've tried:

- getting the  tag to run while removing the svelte:head section, with no luck.
- Removing the function from the  tag on form.svelte, putting it into an external .js file, and importing that script in the svelte:head as a new script, with no luck.
- Running the handleClick function within onMount, with no luck.
- Renaming handleSubmit as handleClick - no luck
- %sapper.scripts% does exist in the template.html file
- The dev site looks good otherwise.

Here's the full form.svelte component code which contains the non-functioning script:

```
<svelte:head>
  <!-- UIkit CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/uikit-3.6.17/css/uikit.css" />

  <!-- UIkit JS -->
  <script src="/uikit-3.6.17/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/uikit-3.6.17/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  export let handleSubmit;
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
      console.log("button clicked");
    };

  onMount(() => {
    console.log("form mounted");
  });
</script>


<div
  uk-scrollspy="target: section; cls: uk-animation-slide-right-medium; delay: 250;"
>
  <section>
    <!--Section Title-->
    <h1 class="title" id="contact">Contact Me</h1>
    <!--Lead Text-->
    <p class="non-lead">
      Feel free to reach out to me at any time. My contact information is below,
      and you can also contact me using the web form below.
    </p>
    <table class="uk-table uk-table-justify uk-table-small">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="row-hover">
          <td>(215)-123-1234</td>
          <td
            ><a href="mailto:@gmail.com" class="link-item"
              ><span class="email-link" uk-icon="mail" /> gmail[at]gmail[dot]com</a
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <!--Contact Form-->
    <form class="uk-form-horizontal uk-margin-medium">
      <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="name">Full Name</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
          <input
            class="uk-input"
            id="name"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First and Last name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
          <input
            class="uk-input"
            id="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email Address"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
          <input
            class="uk-input"
            id="phone"
            type="tel"
            placeholder="Phone Number"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="about">Tell Me About Yourself</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
          <textarea
            rows="5"
            class="uk-textarea"
            id="phone"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Tell me a little about yourself..."
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button on:click={handleSubmit} class="uk-button uk-button-primary"
      >Submit</button
    >
    <button on:click={handleSubmit} class="uk-button uk-button-danger"
      >Cancel</button
    >
  </section>
</div>

<style>
  * {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }

  section {
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 7% 2% 2% 2%;
  }

  .non-lead {
    max-width: 80ch;
    margin: 1em 0;
  }

  .title {
    max-width: 60ch;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    border-bottom: solid 4px rgba(170, 185, 173, 0.75);
  }

  td {
    padding: 1.5% 1.5% !important;
  }

  .row-hover {
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  .row-hover:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #aab9ad;
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
  }

  .row-hover:hover .email-link,
  .row-hover:hover .link-item {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .email-link,
  .link-item {
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

And here is the index.svelte page that imports :

```
<script>
  import Navbar from "../components/navbar.svelte";
  import Form from "../components/form.svelte";
  import Hero from "../components/hero.svelte";
  import MainContent from "../components/main_content.svelte";
  import Footer from "../components/footer.svelte";
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <title>Name</title>
</svelte:head>

<Navbar />
<main>
  <Hero />
  <section>
    <MainContent />
    <Form />
  </section>
</main>
<Footer />

<style>
  main {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
  }
</style>
```

I am seeing the following error in the console; however it appears there regardless of whether I have the  in question in place or not:

[Error in Firefox Dev Edition Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVwQo.png)

I currently have this in a private repo, but I can make it public if people need to see the source.

Thanks,

-Jack

Answer (score 0):

Okey dokey, so I managed to solve the issue! I was abusing the svelte:head attribute.

I had the UIKit CSS and script tags in each component in my Sapper App, so I was calling those scripts and css stylesheets in multiple times.
I didn't notice this to be the issue because I was pretty locked into solving the issue for the  component only.

The solution was to remove the

```
<svelte:head>
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/uikit-3.6.17/css/uikit.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="/uikit-3.6.17/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="/uikit-3.6.17/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</svelte:head>
```

from each component and to move the UIKit stylesheets and scripts to the template.html file. Voila! Can console.log during onMount and handleSubmit! Of course I had to post a question to Stack Overflow first.